# Regular Expression for symbol characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, symbols

I have a quick question about the regular expression for symbols like  `!@#$%^&*()_+` in JavaScript. So, I am trying to implement it for the password validation, and I followed some documentation about regular expressions I found online, but it did not work correctly only for symbols (it worked for numbers and alphabet characters)

The function below is the sample code of what I used on my web application.
When I type a password on the web application, this function always returns false even if I put in symbols.

```
function valid_password(password) {
    var sym = new RegExp('[ @#$%^&_*-+=[]{}()?]+');
    if (sym.test(password)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can just `return sym.test(password)`. No if/else and `return true`/`return false` are required.

Comment: If you have a regular expression meant to match `]`, you can't do it like this: `[]]`. You need to escape the inner `]` so it doesn't close the opening `[`, otherwise it appears to the parser that you have a balanced `[]` pair followed by a random `]`. Done correctly it would look like this: `[\]]`. Because the backslash itself needs to be escaped inside a string. if you use `new RegExp` instead of a regex literally, you also have to escape the \, producing `new RegExp('[\\]]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape special characters in your regex, such as `[`, `]`, `-`. Also, for better performance avoid compiling a new regex each time you call the function, which is only needed when you want to compose a pattern based on variable input. The `.test()` returns true or false, e.g. no need for the if/else.

Here is the function fixed:

```js
function hasSymbol(password) {
    return /[ @#$%^&_*\-+=\[\]{}()\?]/.test(password);
}

[ 'abc', 'a@z', 'a z', '+++' ].forEach(password => {
  let check = hasSymbol(password);
  console.log(password, '=>', check);
});
```

Output:

```
abc => false
a@z => true
a z => true
+++ => true
```

This tests for a single symbol in a password. You might want to test for at least a number of symbols. You can do that with a positive lookahead. Here is an example for at least 3 symbols:

```js
function hasThreeSymbols(password) {
    return /^(?=(?:.*?[ @#$%^&_*\-+=\[\]{}()\?]){3,})/.test(password);
}

[ 'abc', 'a@z', 'a z', '+++', 'a#b$c', 'a#b$c^d' ].forEach(password => {
  let check = hasThreeSymbols(password);
  console.log(password, '=>', check);
});
```

Output:

```
abc => false
a@z => false
a z => false
+++ => true
a#b$c => false
a#b$c^d => true
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(?=` -- positive lookahead start

  - `(?:` -- non-capture group start

    - `.*?` -- non-greedy scan for:
    - `[ @#$%^&_*\-+=\[\]{}()\?]` -- a single symbol
  - `)` -- non-capture group end
  - `{3,}` -- require 3+ occurrences of previous pattern, e.g. capture group
- `)` -- positive lookahead end

To learn more about regex: https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex